# Angularjs no lo reconoce ipad

Tags: angularjs, ios

cuando ejecuto mi aplicacion en ipad me da este error

```
Error[$injector:modulerr]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=’undefined%20is%20not%20an%20object
```

mi aplicacion angularjs es:

```
var app = angular.module('nexionfiPortal', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngRoute', 
])

.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
    })

.when('/email', {
    templateUrl: 'views/email.html',
    controller: 'EmailCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'email'
})

.when('/usuario/premios/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/premios.html',
    controller: 'PremiosCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'premios'
})
```

Comment: esto te funciona en iphone?

Comment: Puedo leer en el error `undefined is not an object`, parece un problema de código. Puedes compartir la url del error o el mensaje completo del error?
Estás usando algún minificador o compresor de js?

Comment: Esto es un clásico mensaje de error de angular cuando se ejecuta con el código minificado. Usa la versión sin minificar para que te imprima el error correctamente. Edita la pregunta y agrega la información adicional que te muestre la consola para poder ayudarte